# Apostrophes for showing possession on the word "structure"

Tags: grammaticality

I often use the word "structure", as in "the structure of a building".

I always thought the word structure was singular, so to show possession I would use:

> "The structure's properties are impressive"

However, whenever co-authors look at my work they edit it to:

> "The structures' properties are impressive".

Why are they moving the apostrophe? Is there a better way to express that I am treating "structure" as a singular noun?

Comment: I'm with you. Maybe your co-authors think that the properties of more than one structure are intended.

Comment: If it is being used as a singular structure, then you would be correct in your usage. Maybe they are confused as to what you are referencing, as @Chaim suggests.

Comment: You could avoid this by writing "The properties of the structure are impressive." This would be clearer, both for your colleagues and also your general readers.

Comment: At first glance, it appears that your co-authors believe you are using the plural form, "structures." This would answer why they've moved the apostrophe to the end of the word. Since you're intending on the singular, I'd say you're correct in your usage.

Comment: As you pose the question, you're asking ELU contributors to guess your co-authors' reasons. You should ask them (they may be erroneous).

Comment: I have to agree with @Mick, the way I formulate my comment should just be reworded to avoided this issue with other readers as I won't be there to "correct" readers in the future.

Answer (score -1):

There are two possibilities.

One is that you've explained the problem quite badly, which doesn't look very likely.

The other is that your colleagues are mistaken.

Comment: Coo… that was kind of someone. What's the problem there, please?